# playing .aac audio on Windows Azure with JW Player : doesn't work in Flash Mode

Tags: flash, azure, cross-domain, jwplayer, aac

I run a JW Player on Windows Azure:

```
<div id="container">Loading the player ...</div> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jwplayer("container").setup({
            file: "http://fmw.blob.core.windows.net/publicfiles/fmwa-" + "<%=get_audio_id()%>" + ".aac",
            height: 270,
            width: 480,
            'modes': [
                    { type: 'html5' },
                    { type: 'flash', src: 'player.swf' },
                    { type: 'download' }
                    ]
        }); 
    </script>
```

JW Player runs in HTML5 Mode as default. If HTML5 doesn't work, it will automatically run in Flash Mode (e.g., IE doesn't support playing .aac with HTML5).

For Flash Mode I have a `crossdomain.xml` at http://fmw.blob.core.windows.net/crossdomain.xml
(the webpage on azure is with domain `*.cloudapp.net`, but the storage is with `*.windows.net`, so that they are not in the same domain)

Here's the problem: **it works fine in HTML5 Mode**(Mac safari/iOS safari), **but doesn't work in Flash Mode**(IE/Chrome). The error message is: **Video not found or access denied.**

Please Help!

A test example: http://fmw.cloudapp.net/default.aspx?fmwa=06dc832b-3c55-45f2-9391-332b448f892d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, nobody replied yet..

My answer is to **convert .aac into .mp3**, then it will work. The reason is hard to explain  according to [my discussion with the support staff of JW Player](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/forums/jw-player/servers-and-streaming/24172/video-not-found-in-flash-mode-but-works-well-in-html5-mode), there is no way to make sure why there was a difference between the two modes. I think the problem is the poor support to AAC audio by Flash. It works with MP3.

So, if you are facing the same problem, don't waste time to solve this, just go ahead to convert your audio file into MP3.